# Maximum amount deducted for carried-over long term capital loss

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

Suppose I have $10K of long term capital losses in FY2018.  I'm married filing jointly, so the max I can deduct is $3K, and carry over $7K to the next year.

**Question**: do I then have to deduct $3K against capital gains (long-term only? can I use short-term too?), or can I somehow deduct all $7K against income and/or gains.

I want to avoid the hassle of book-keeping and tracking losses for two-to-three years if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $7k can offset gains next year, long term or short, and up to $3K of ordinary income.

I assume you do your taxes by hand? Else tax software makes the carry-forward pretty simple.

Comment: Perfect -- appreciate it.  That's how I read the tax code as well, but wanted to confirm.  Thanks so much!